# Block View - Most Time Consuming - Optimise

Tags: views, blocks, caching, database

I have a block view showing the title and thumbnail of an amazon store item (from the Amazon Store module).  According to New Relic tool it shows that this block view is the most time consuming (1050sec).  As you can see from the settings I've put on caching, but it doesnt improve the performance.  Any advise?

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT amazon_item_image.url AS amazon_item_image_url, amazon_item_image.height AS amazon_item_image_height, amazon_item_image.width AS amazon_item_image_width, amazon_item.detailpageurl AS amazon_item_detailpageurl, amazon_item_image.asin AS amazon_item_image_asin, amazon_item.title AS amazon_item_title, amazon_item.asin AS asin
FROM 
{amazon_item} amazon_item
LEFT JOIN {amazon_item_image} amazon_item_image ON amazon_item.asin = amazon_item_image.asin AND amazon_item_image.size = 'mediumimage'
WHERE (( (amazon_item.asin LIKE '1846680972' ESCAPE '\\') ))
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Here are my settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is wall time, it probably is taking into account the network time it takes to grab the image etc from amazon.  And, if this is the case, no amount of caching of the query and html will help out.

Comment: Hi I reckon that is the case, what I've done is abandon having a view for this type of block and opted to manually add the book image and link to the amazon store item.